# Modify CSV file

Tags: perl, csv

I need to read the input CSV file, and change the header and some values as follows.

Can anybody help me to achieve this?

**Input File**

```
Level;Ref;Number;Ref Code
0;Ref1;4;16
1;Ref6;2;32
4;Ref9;7;8
6;Ref2;6;32
```

**Output File:**

```
Level1;Ref;Ref Code
0;Reference1;16
1;Reference6;32
4;Reference9;8
6;Reference2;32
```

I started with this code but I don't know how to change the header.

```perl
my $file = 'Classeur1.csv';
my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { binary => 1, eol => $/, sep_char => ';' } );
open my $io, "<", $file or die "$file: $!";

my $cols1 = $csv->column_names($csv->getline($io));
while ( my $href = $csv->getline_hr($io) ) {
    print Dumper( \$href );
}

close $io;
```

#### Dumper output

```
$VAR1 = { 'Number' => '4', 'Level' => '0', 'Ref Code' => '16', 'Ref' => 'Ref1' };
$VAR1 = { 'Number' => '2', 'Level' => '1', 'Ref Code' => '32', 'Ref' => 'Ref6' };
$VAR1 = { 'Number' => '7', 'Level' => '4', 'Ref Code' => '8',  'Ref' => 'Ref9' };
$VAR1 = { 'Number' => '6', 'Level' => '6', 'Ref Code' => '32', 'Ref' => 'Ref2' };
```

Comment: You will need a second Text::CSV instance to write to. What does your Dumper output say? You don't need the backslash in front of `$href`, it is already a reference.

Answer (score 2):

The core [`Tie::File`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::File) module can help you here. It allows you to access a file through a tied array, so that any changes to the array are reflected in the contents of the file

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Tie::File;

tie my @file, 'Tie::File', 'Classeur1.csv';

$file[0]  =~ s/Level/Level1/;
$file[$_] =~ s/Ref(\d+)/Reference$1/ for 1 .. $#file;
```